# How can I do some functionality if annotation present?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, reflection, annotations

So, the problem is next:
I have a class that is responsible for WebDriver. Every WebDriver object is a Singletone so, I use ThreadLocal for use this driver in many tests.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadLocalScope = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
    @Override
    protected WebDriver initialValue() {
        ConfigProperty configProperty = new ConfigProperty();
        System.setProperty(configProperty.getChromeDriver(), configProperty.getUrl());
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addExtensions(new File(configProperty.getChromeExtension()));
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }
};

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
    return threadLocalScope.get();
}
```

As you can see, when the driver start it install some extension for Google Chrome, but not in each test this extension is necessary.

So, I want to create an Annotation something like @InstallExtension, and in runtime see for this. If annotation is present under my test it will install for WebDriver this extension, in other way - not.
How can I do it?

Comment: If I understand your need properly, something like this should do the trick: `if (yourClass.getMethod("name", null).isAnnotationPresent(Annotation.class)) {...}`

Comment: @HBo He'll also need to set the retention to runtime in his annotation.

Comment: @killjoy damn, too slow! :) Good catch

Comment: yes, it's good. But, my driver is creating in @BeforeMethod (TestNG) before each test. I don't exectly knowe what test will be the next.

Comment: @RomanShmandrovskyi Why not pass a boolean parameter to the BeforeMethod? Instantiate the driver accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate my comment:
Once your annotation is created, like so (assuming the annotation's target is a method, otherwise just change the target to FIELD, ...):

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD})
public @interface InstallExtension{}
```

In your code, you need something like this:

```
if (yourClass.getMethod("name", null).isAnnotationPresent(InstallExtension.class)) {
...
}
```

Comment: Maby I not correctly asking my questions.
My driver created in BeforMethod (this method will be runned before each test) by calling method homeBO.openHomePage();
And on this moment I must to know what test will be runned next, to get him annotation and make specific WebDriver (with extension or not)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface AnAnnotation {
    String value();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void testBeforeMethod(Method method) {
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(AnAnnotation.class)) 
        System.out.println("Annotation is " + method.getAnnotationsByType(AnAnnotation.class)[0].value() );
    System.out.println("Before Test");
}

@AnAnnotation("ExtensionName")
@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("Test 1 Test");
}
```